# How to transfer Google Cloud Project to another email account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a google cloud project that is linked to a Firebase project and an Android and iOS app, both currently in production. I want to move the cloud project to another email without disturbing the existing app services. By extension I also want to transfer the billing to the new account

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the project email address but you need to  keep in mind that for every project there will be an email account currently tied to account 1 (so, every project in that production environment), you will need to change the attached Billing Account to account 2. Follow below steps to change the email account for the project:

1. Go to your Console.
2. Go to the Menu, and select "`IAM & Admin`"
3. Add new mail as owner.
4. On new Owner's account, go to Billing and link the project to an existing billing account or set up a new Billing account.
5. "Remove" the role of an "`owner`" for account 1 of the project in "`IAM & Admin`".

For more information follow [Manage access to projects](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access?visit_id=638287939968133907-1566305656&rd=1) and [changing a billing account for a project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#change_the_billing_account_for_a_project).

Comment: Thanks for this. What happens if the domain and Google Workspace of the first organisation expires. Would access to the project still remain with the 2nd email account that is now the owner after following your steps?

Comment: If you've made purchases from Google Cloud Marketplace in your project, be sure to make those same purchases in the new Cloud Billing account before switching the project. Follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/manage-billing) for more information.